# How to use helpers in Sails v0.11.0 while using handlebars

Tags: sails.js, handlebars.js

I want to be using handlebar helper functions with Sails `v0.11.0` , but cant understand how to configure them.

There is a solution which works with previous versions [helpers in sails](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2414) , but not sure how it would work in `v0.11.0`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not best aproach but it finaly works for me.

When sails is configured to use handlebars it uses `express-handlebars` package which is installed as dependency. This `express-handlebars` uses instance of its dependency package `handlebars`. You need to use registerHelper method on this instance.

I created `config/helpers.js` with this content:

```
var handlebars = require("../node_modules/sails/node_modules/express-handlebars/node_modules/handlebars");

handlebars.registerHelper('decorateElement', function (context) {
  return "<span class='red'>" + context + "</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to install handlebars

```
npm i -S handlebars
```

Then you just need to register a helper. I like to make a `helper.js`-file in the `config`-folder for clarity.

Let's say you want to be able to render json:

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars');

handlebars.registerHelper('json', function (context) {
  return JSON.stringify(context);
});
```

Then, in your views you would just write the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var object = {{{json example}}};

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand this, but does this work for you @thole in `v0.11.0` ? In this version all config files must export a function , I cannot just add config directly. If I do , I get missing helper error in my template.

Comment: @user108203 Hmm, that's odd. :( It works great for me in 0.11. Have you changed your rendering engine to handlebars as well?

Comment: Yes , I have the handlebars templating engine and partials working.  Also in the view my files have `.handlebars` extension so do I still need to add script tags ?

Comment: @user108203 I see. No, you don't need the script-tags :) It was just an example. You should be able to use the helper anywhere in the view. Hopefully someone else can help. I'm clueless. :(

Comment: I am also facing same issue, does anyone know how to use even the standard handlebar blocks or helper functions? #for #while, etc.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution for people using sailsjs 0.12 is to add a config/helpers.js file that exports the helper functions:

```
module.exports = {
  ifCond (v1, v2, options) {
    if (v1 === v2) {
      return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
  },
  json (context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
  }
};
```

and in the config/views.js file add the following :

```
helpers: require("./helpers"),
```